# Implement Login and Register form Animation in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, animation, expression-blend, silverlight-5.0, blend

In silverlight business application template ,we have a login and register childwindow with an animation.How can i implement this animation for other childwindow in my silverlight application?!! 
 -any sample 
 -any step by step guid

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must use Expression blend to implement this animation.
Look following link :
http://forums.silverlight.net/t/181996.aspx/1